# What is the right code for the UIPopoverController

Tags: swift, ios9, uipopovercontroller

What is the right code for the PopoverController in iOS 9 have anywhere the right code for this code?

---

@IBAction func share(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

```
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController (
        activityItems: [(webview.request?.URL!.absoluteString)! as NSString],
        applicationActivities: nil)

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        //iPad

        let activityPopover = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: activityViewController)
        activityPopover.presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem(self.shareButton, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
    }
    else
    {
        //iPhone
        presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ancient. You should throw all of that away. In iOS 8 and iOS 9, presented controllers adapt. UIActivityViewController is already a popover on iPad, automatically. Just present it and the right thing will happen.

Of course, you will have to supply it with a `sourceView` and `sourceRect` or a bar button item source. Otherwise, you'll crash on the iPad. But that's the case for *any* popover, so you can't be surprised about it.

Comment: Example code from my book: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch13p635activityView/ch26p901activityView/ViewController.swift